# Syntax Checking in Notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++

I am currently programming Python on Notepad++. Many times I have been bogged down by typos and misspellings. It's becoming frustrating to find those errors when writing so many lines of code. Is there syntax checking for Notepad++? I know a SO user offered a script like this:

```
console.show()
console.clear()
console.run('cmd.exe /c '
            + 'C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\pylint.bat --reports=n -f parseable '
            + '"%s"' % notepad.getCurrentFilename())
```

But when I added it to Notepad++, created an icon out of it, nothing happened. How do I use this script?

Comment: What is the problem?  What have you tried?  What is the output?  What is the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

First install Pylint and its dependencies. I also added `pylint.bat` to Python27/Scripts. Downloaded Python Scripts. Then go to `Show Console` under `Plugins` and `Scripts`. Make sure to have a .py file open. Enter in

> console.run('cmd.exe /c '
>               + 'C:\Python27\Scripts\pylint.bat --reports=n -f parseable '
>               + '"%s"' % notepad.getCurrentFilename())

And it will give you a list of errors.

Comment: what plugin do you use to "show consolder under plugins and scripts"? could you specify the plugin name to install from *menu>plugins>plugin manager*, and clarify if I understand well that what you've written means *menu>Plugins>Scripts>Show Console* for real?

Comment: from another answer I figured out that this is the ***Python Script*** plugin. So the menu is: *menu>Plugins>Python Script>Show Console*. But first Install "Python Script". I already had it, but supposedly from *menu>Plugins>Plugin Manager*, or else check the other answer for link. The other answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987920/python-correctness-i-e-lint-analyzing-for-notepad

Answer (score 0):

For Python (also Perl, PHP, Ruby, Javascript) development, I would recommend using Activestate [Komodo IDE](http://activestate.com/komodo) - it is very powerful, has live syntax checking, code completion, debugger, regex toolkit, works and looks almost identical on Windows, Mac and Linux, etc.

However, Komodo IDE is commercial tool and is not free (it costs $200+). Fortunately, there is free open source flavor of it called [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit). It still has the same great live syntax checker and syntax highlighter, but it does not have Python debugger. Give it a try - it is very good editor.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using [SynWrite](http://uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/) editor, it has simpler external tools configuring. You can also call PyLint tool ang go to errors, but easier than in Notepad++, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Anaconda Environment Spyder provides a very useful and helpful Syntax checker that does exactly what you have been Looking for